# Subviews in presented ViewController gets wrong position after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uisearchcontroller

I'm experimenting with `UISearchController`, but I can't get it right. I **present** a clean `UISearchController` from my own `UIViewController`, and it looks great - but as soon as I rotate the device, it gets shifted a few points up or down.

To recreate this, just do these few steps:

1. Create a new Single View project
2. Delete `Main.storyboard` from the project files **and** remove its name from the project settings (Project -> General -> Target -> Main Interface)

In `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...{
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

`ViewController.swift`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 100, height: 40))
        button.setTitle("Search", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    @objc func click(){
        self.present(UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And that's it. This is what I'm seeing:
[image: this]

Presenting the search when the device is in portrait mode looks great in portrait - but if you rotate the device to landscape while presenting the searchbar, it will be wrongly positioned, a few pixels above the top of the screen.

Presenting the search when in landscape will yield the opposite. It looks great in landscape, but when rotating it to portrait the entire search controller view will be pushed down a few pixels.

It's not a matter of height size on the bar. The entire bar gets pushed up/down.

I tried investigating a bit further. I presented the search controller from landscape mode and rotated to portrait, and then debugged the view hierarchy:

[image: debug]

To be honest, I'm not quite sure what I'm looking at. The top-most view is a `UISearchBarBackground` embedded within a `_UISearchBarContainerView`, which is within a `_UISearchControllerView`.

As you can see in the size inspector on the right side, the middle-view "container" has `y: 5`, which makes no sense. When debugging the correct state, y is 0. What's really interesting is that the top-most view has `y: -44` in this corrupt situation, and it has the same when it's correct - but you can clearly see that there is some space leftover above it. There seem to be three different y-positions. I don't get it.

I've read some guides on how to implement a `UISearchController`, but literally every single example I find is people modally presenting a custom ViewController that contains a SearchController. This will result in the entire custom ViewController being animated up from below.

Since the `UISearchController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, I wanted to test out presenting it directly, not as part of a regular `UIViewController`. This gives the cool effect that the searchBar animates in from above, and the keyboard from below.

But why doesn't this work?

**Edit:** I just found out that if I enable `Hide status bar` in the project settings, the `UISearchController` looks even more correct in landscape than the "correct state" from above, and even animates correctly to portrait. It's super weird, because the status bar doesn't change at all. It was never visible in landscape. Why does this happen? It seems so buggy. Look at these three states:
[image: landscape]

The first state is when showing search controller from portrait then rotating to landscape (doesn't matter if `Hide status bar` is enabled or not.

The second state is when showing search controller from landscape if `Hide status bar` is false

The third state is when showing search controller from landscape if `Hide status bar` is true.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller):

> Although a UISearchController object is a view controller, you should
>   never present it directly from your interface. If you want to present
>   the search results interface explicitly, wrap your search controller
>   in a UISearchContainerViewController object and present that object
>   instead.

Try to wrap your `UISearchController` inside a `UISearchContainerViewController`.

Comment: Interesting! I need to learn how to read.
But this doesn't exactly work. If I change `self.present(UISearchContainerViewController(searchController:UISearchController:searchResultsController:nil))` I just get a black screen with an invisible search bar. Does it mean that `self` has to be a UISearchContainerViewController perhaps?.. I'll have to test some things out..
This doesn't use the nice animation from above either, it seems..

Comment: Actually, the documentation for `UISearchContainerViewController` says the following: 
_Although you can present a search controller object modally, you should never push one onto a navigation controller’s stack or use one as a child of another container view controller. Instead, embed an instance of this class and let it manage the presentation of the search controller’s content._

**Although you can present a search controller object modally** - isn't that exactly what I'm trying to do? I get the feeling that the documentation you found is more directed to self.addChild(sc), which I'm not

Comment: e.g, I'm **not** pushing it onto the navigation stack, and I'm not using it as child of anything. I'm just trying to present it modally.

Answer (score 0):

How about make a custom view contains search bar. 
Make it on top of the layers.

And when rotate occurs update frame/constraints of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in guidelines for designing for iPhone X. Now Navigation bar contains search controller. You can instanciate the search controller and set it to navigationItem.searchController. Now it will handle the search controller while rotation.

```
var search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.navigationItem.searchController = search
```

Comment: I know, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve. My ViewController doesn't have a navigationBar (i.e no navigationItem), but it needs to modally display a search controller. To solve this, I'd have to create a ViewController within a UINavigationController, then set its navigationItem. As I mentioned, that's how everybody does it. The result will be a full UIViewController animating in from below. According to the documentation, and the fact that the UISearchController takes in a searchResultsController, it should be possible to present it without having a NavigationController.

Comment: As you can see in my example code, there's not a single UINavigationController being used, yet it's still presented in the "correct" way. It appears to be presented in a bar of some sorts, which I assume is one of the intended ways to present it (outside NavCon).
I'd like to keep that fancy animation where the searchbar comes down from above and the keyboard from below. And even the transparent background so that I can see through to the original ViewController when there aren't any results, and tap to dismiss it all.

Answer (score -3):

**You can do this tric**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 100, height: 40))
    button.setTitle("Search", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .black
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)


}

@objc func click(){
    self.present(sc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    var mFrame = sc.view.frame
    mFrame.origin.y = 5.0
    sc.view.frame = mFrame
}
```

Comment: This is not proper solution. It will add extra space above sc even device in portrait mode.